# argparse: How to specify custom help text for subparsers?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse, subparsers

Using `argparse` under `python3`, I'm trying to get subparser help text and sub-subparser help text to be set in customized ways. The following example program illustrates my issue (the example program's source code appears at the bottom of this message). This example program should be run as follows:

`argtest cmd [ ... args ... ]`
or
`argtest special subcmd [ ... args ... ]`
where "cmd" can be "cmd00", "cmd01", etc.,
and "subcmd" can be "sub00", "sub01", etc.

When I run it like `argtest cmd00 -h`, I want to get specific help for the "cmd00" command.
When I run it like `argtest special sub00 -h`, I want to get specific help for the "sub00" special command.

However, I am not getting these help values.
Given the code below, when I run this command:

```
% argtest special -h
```

... I get this output:

```
usage: argtest (toplevel) special [-h] [--debug] {sub00,sub01} ...

positional arguments:
  {sub00,sub01}
    sub00        sub00 toplevel help
    sub01        sub01 toplevel help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --debug
```

However, what I want is the following:

```
special toplevel help

positional arguments:
  {sub00,sub01}
    sub00        sub00 toplevel help
    sub01        sub01 toplevel help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --debug
```

Likewise, when I run this:

```
% argtest special sub00 -h
```

... I get this output:

```
usage: argtest (toplevel) special sub00 [-h] [--debug] [--sub0 SUB0]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --debug
  --sub0 SUB0  sub0-help
```

However, I want this:

```
sub00 toplevel help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --debug
  --sub0 SUB0  sub0-help
```

It seems like the lower-level help values get ignored, and the help is always forced to use the default help for the top level, which then generates help for all of the sub-parsers.

Is there any way that I can get the help messages that I want, given that I am using subparsers nested sub-subparsers? Thank you very much.

**Here is the example program**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                              

import os
import sys
import argparse

prog = None

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=f'{prog} (toplevel)')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--verbose',
        dest='VERBOSE',
        action='store_true',
        help='verbose output'
    )

    globalopts = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    globalopts.add_argument(
        '--debug',
        dest='DEBUG',
        action='store_true'
    )

    command = parser.add_subparsers(
        dest='CMD',
        help=f'{prog} CMD [ ... args ... ]'
    )

    command_00 = command.add_parser('cmd00',
                                    parents=[globalopts], help='cmd00 toplevel help')
    command_00.add_argument('--a', dest='A',
                            default=None, required=0, help='cmd00-a-help')

    command_01 = command.add_parser('cmd01',
                                    parents=[globalopts], help='cmd01 toplevel help')
    command_01.add_argument('--b', dest='B',
                            default=None, required=0, help='cmd00-b-help')

    # etc. ... lots of others, up to up to command_99                                                                                                     

    special = command.add_parser('special',
                                 parents=[globalopts], add_help='special toplevel help')
    subparsers = special.add_subparsers(dest='SUBPARSERS')

    special_00 = subparsers.add_parser('sub00',
                                       parents=[globalopts], help='sub00 toplevel help')
    special_00.add_argument('--sub0', dest='SUB0',
                            default=None, required=0, help='sub0-help')

    special_01 = subparsers.add_parser('sub01',
                                        parents=[globalopts], help='sub01 toplevel help')
    special_01.add_argument('--sub1', dest='SUB1',
                            default=None, required=0, help='sub1-help')

    args, unknowns = parser.parse_known_args()

    print(f'args={vars(args)}')

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prog = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: This is too big of a question to digest in a quick read.  I have a vague memory of looking into the `usage` generation with subparsers on the Python bug/issues board.  I'll see if I can find it.  In mean time, look at how `prog` is handled in `add_subparsers` and `add_parser`.  Normally `prog` comes from `sys.argv[0]`, but with subparsers it is customized to include required arguments of the main parser, plus the subparsers name.  I think you want to customize the `prog` and `usage`, not the `help`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into `prog` and `usage` and see if they can solve my problem.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue42297 "[argparse] Bad error message formatting when using custom usage text" is the bug/issue I had in mind.  It's about the error message generated in the subparser, but that includes the `usage`.

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar error with `prog`, but I just got around it by doing this: `usage=f'{prog} etc. etc.'` (where "prog" is my own variable) instead of `usage='%(prog)s etc. etc.'`. And I think that my problem is indeed likely to be solveable via the `usage` attribute. It works in my example program, but now I'm testing in my real-world program, which is more complicated. I'll report back here when I have my results.

Comment: One more thing which I forgot to mention until now: even though I think I can get the help text I want via the `usage` attribute, I'm still getting default help text when there are error messages. I'm wondering if something in addition to the `usage` attribute might be needed in order to control the error text.